# T-cyclic subspaces and dimensionality?

Tags: linear-algebra

For each linear operator T on vector space V, find an ordered basis for the T-cyclic subspace generated by vector z.

$V=\mathbb R^4$

$T(a,b,c,d)=(a+b,b-c,a+c,a+d)$

$z=e_1$ ($e_1$ is the first standard basis in $\mathbb R^4$ so $(1,0,0,0))$

So basically I got the first 3 Transforms as...

$T(z)=(1,0,1,1)$

$T^2(z)=(1,-1,2,2)$

$T^3(z)=(0,-3,3,3)$

I have the solution here with me and it says that the basis is $(z,T(z),T^2(z))$

My question is, why doesn't it use $T^3(z)$ in the basis, why isn't a fourth vector needed to span the subspace? Why is the dimension only $3$ not $4$?

Comment: I think I got it actually. Do you simply just have to recognize that you can write T^3(z) as a linear combination of z,T(z) and T^2(z)? Is there an easier way to see that the subspace will be dimension 3?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $-3(T(z)-T^2(z))=-3(0,1,-1,-1)=(0,-3,3,3)=T^3(z)$. So, $T^3(z)$ can be obtained from the previous terms, i.e. $T^3(z)$ is not independent of $z,T(z),T^2(z)$. Hence, it's not in the given basis.

Comment: Just realized this too. Do you simply have to recognize that? Or is there an easier way to see that the subspace will be dimensionality 3?

Comment: @user139985: There is no "abstract" proof that will work for all operators: consider the operator that takes $e_i $ to $e_{i+1}$, then the dimension would be $4$ and not 3. So, for this particular operator, you have to invoke some extra trick- like the one that you found. Other ways could be to look at the determinant of the matrix spanned by these 4 vectors- the det is $0$ and hence these vectors aren't ind.